# AActor set mobility in ue4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

How to set Actor by default in the Mobility section change from static to movable in c++.
I know that you can just change the engine to select an item, but I want to understand what method in c++ allows you to change the Mobility section.
I read the documentation and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actors are made up of Components, the RootComponent gives the Actor its Transform and Mobility within the Scene.

Each component can have its own Mobility.

Use the following function to change Mobility of a given component.

```
MySceneComponent->SetMobility(EComponentMobility::Movable);
```